# Set an array equal to another, then change the first array without affecting the second

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array 'a' and I later set a new array 'b' equal to 'a'. When I remove an element from either array, they both change rather than the explicitly referenced array. I think this is because they're pointing to the same underlying object?

```
a= ["cat","hat","dog"]
b= a
a.delete_at(0)
print a
>> a = ["hat","dog"
print b
>> b = ["hat","dog"]
```

How can I set two variables equal but allow them to be independent for later operations? I'm looking for behaviour like this:

```
a= ["cat","hat","dog"]
b= a
a.delete_at(0)
print a
>> a = ["hat","dog"
print b
>> b = ["cat","hat","dog"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Object#dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) to create a duplicate of the original array:

```
a = ["cat","hat","dog"]
b = a.dup # b now points to a duplicate of a, not a itself

b # => ["cat","hat","dog"]
b.delete_at(0)

b # => ["hat","dog"]
a # => ["cat","hat","dog"]
```

To verify this behavior:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a.object_id == b.object_id # => true, a and b point to the same objects

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.dup
a.object_id == b.object_id # => false, a and b point to different objects
```

Comment: I just noticed that the "DUP" method doesn't work when doing string manipulations. For example, if I do b[0].upcase! the first element of both arrays is changed. Any insight into that?

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps worth noting that if

```
a = [["cat", "pig"], "hat", "dog"] # => [["cat", "pig"], "hat", "dog"]
b = a.dup                          # => [["cat", "pig"], "hat", "dog"]
```

then

```
a[0].delete_at(0)
a                                  # => [["pig"], "hat", "dog"] 
b                                  # => [["pig"], "hat", "dog"]
```

Here you'd need to do this:

```
a = [["cat", "pig"], "hat", "dog"]
b = a.dup 
b[0] = a[0].dup
a[0].delete_at(0)
a                                  # => [["pig"], "hat", "dog"] 
b                                  # => [["cat", "pig"], "hat", "dog"]
```

Now suppose `a` were much more complicated, say, an array of hashes whose values are arrays of hashes.  Obviously, one must take care in making a copy of `a` that will be unaffected by the deletion of some deeply-nested element of `a`.  What you would want is called a "deep copy", as opposed to the "shallow" copy made by [Object#dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) and [Object#clone](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-clone).

Fortunately, there is an easy way to make a deep-copy of any object, using [Marshal#dump](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) and [Marshal#load](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-load):

```
b = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))
a[0].delete_at(0)
a                                  #  => [["pig"], "hat", "dog"]
b                                  #  => [["cat", "pig"], "hat", "dog"]
```

As an aside, `Marshal` is also used to save an object to file for later retrieval:

```
File.open('myfile', 'w+') do |f|  
  Marshal.dump(a, f)  
end  

File.open('myfile') do |f|  
  c = Marshal.load(f)  
end  
c                                  #  => [["cat", "pig"], "hat", "dog"]
```

A word of caution: Marshal files are not not portable among all versions of Ruby.